# Non parametric tests for relation/association between variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, nonparametric, independence, kruskal-wallis-test

What could be an appropriate test for checking whether there exist any relationship between Net Promoter Score ( Categorical in nature with 0 meaning detractor, 1 meaning Neutral, 2 meaning Promter ) and other variable Retention ( 0 meaning did not retain,1 meaning retained) 
The distribution of NPS is not normal and thus parametric tests are not applicable. Also in the sample comparing means would not be helpful( I think ).
The two variable are derived from a single customer.

I am using scipy library in Python to run the test.

Comment: This statement: "The distribution of NPS is not normal" does not in any way imply 
that "parametric tests are not applicable"; you no doubt mean something else there. See the first paragraph of the Wikipedia entry on [parametric statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics); note that the discussion of 'parametric" doesn't mention normality at all. There are parametric tests that don't assume normality and on the other hand it may be perfectly reasonable to use a nonparametric test even when you're certain you have normality (you might use an efficient nonparametric test)

Comment: When you say "any relationship" do you intend any kind of association whatever, or are you looking for some kind of monotonic relationship? (e.g. that P(retained) either increases or decreases across NPS)

Comment: Since one of the two variables is binary, you could descriptively compare the retain proportion (= mean of a binary variable) across the three levels of promotor score. Differences might reveal relationships. In order to test the working hypothesis that there is some true relationship, you can go for a chi-squared test of association or something in that direction. How many observations do you have of that single customer?

Comment: Thanks everyone for guidance . There are 98000 observation. Yes glen , something of that sort whether retained increases or decrease across nps groups but this could be checked through crosstab. I was of the thought that , can a statistic test can prove or disprove the hypothesis . Null Hypothesis being there is no relationship of NPS group with retention and alternate being there exist  relationship between NPS group with retentoon.

Comment: There are 98000 overall observation of 97000 customers and 1000 customer have given NPS twice so they have 2 observation for different stages.